# unable to calculate the distance betweeen two points in google maps

Tags: javascript, html, api, google-maps, distance

I am working on a project in which I need to calculate the distance between two points. 
I just used the distancefrom function. I am just cruious, when I alert, the result is correct. However, When I use document.getElementById, it does not work. 
I am wondering whether anybody here can help me to figure out what happened in my  code......
Thank you so much!

```
<html>
<head>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script>
    google.maps.LatLng.prototype.distanceFrom = function(newLatLng) {
        if (newLatLng==undefined) return false;

        var dLat = (newLatLng.lat()-this.lat()) * Math.PI / 180;
        var dLon = (newLatLng.lng()-this.lng()) * Math.PI / 180;
        var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) + Math.cos(this.lat() * Math.PI / 180 ) * Math.cos(newLatLng.lat() * Math.PI / 180 )* Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2);
        return 6371000 * 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
      }

</script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
var loc1 = new google.maps.LatLng(52.5773139, 1.3712427);
var loc2 = new google.maps.LatLng(52.4788314, 1.7577444);
alert (Math.round(loc1.distanceFrom(loc2)/10)/160 + 'mi');
document.getElementById("1").innerHTML=Math.round(loc1.distanceFrom(loc2)/10)/160 + 'mi';
</script>
        <p id="1">xyz
        </p>


        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: A quick Google search provided this page, http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html - it has Javascript variables with the math behind how to calculate distance and bearing.

Comment: Please elaborate "it does not work". Nothing happens? Getting unexpected results? An error occurs? Other? Ähh.. actually put your `p` before the `script`.

Answer (score 0):

Your script is including the Google Maps Javascript API v3:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

That API does not have a distanceFrom method of google.maps.LatLng objects.  To calculate the (straight-line) distance between two coordinates in the v3 API use the [geometry library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry) [computeDistanceBetween](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical) method.